# angularFire and Authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Taking the TodoMVC example into consideration (https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/tree/gh-pages/examples/todomvc), if I were to add authentication to this app, how could I handle the visibility of a user - i.e. if User1 adds todo items, I'd like to make sure that it's only visible to them and if User2 logs in, he doesn't see User1's items. How can I achieve this?

On top of this - I guess this second question is somewhat relevant to the previous one - what is the best way to store todos and users and the visibility of each todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we're talking about [Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) for authentication, the `user` object will contain an ID (with custom login, you will determine the contents). Split the todos up by user id, storing them in separate paths.

```
/todos/user_id/...
```

Then in security rules, after login, the `auth` object contains the user's id, so you can secure each path by user:

```
"todos": {
   "$user_id": {
       ".read": "auth.id === $user_id",
       ".write": "auth.id === $user_id",
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are going to use multiple providers, then you will also want to split this up by provider, since ids are only unique for a given provider.

```
/todos/provider_id/user_id
"todos": {
   "$provider_id": {
       "$user_id": {
           ".read": "auth.id === $user_id && auth.provider === $provider_id",
           ".write": "auth.id === $user_id && auth.provider === $provider_id",
       }
   }
}
```